# How to Upload Image file Into Server along with my string params Using Volley

Tags: android, server, android-volley, image-uploading

I am Trying to upload Images using volley library, I dont know How exactly.

I have referred previously asked questions, but nothing seems to satisfy.

Here is what i needed to acheive :

[image]

Below is the Code I tried to use :

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    Log.d("**********", " Response Received is  " + response);

                    try {

                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                        Log.d("**********", "STRING TO JSON CONVERSION DONE , IT IS   " + jsonObject.toString());

                        ParseReqOtp parseReqOtp = new ParseReqOtp();
                        parseReqOtp.parseImageupload(jsonObject);


                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d("**********", "ERROR IN STRING TO JSON CONVERSION     " + e.toString());

                    }
                    Log.d("**********", "FETCHING IN VOLLEY REQ" + response);




                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(AddPic.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected HashMap<String,String> getParams() {

           HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("id", BaseActivity.getBaseActivity().getEstablishment_id());
        params.put("type", "photos");
        params.put("example_file",file.toString());

        }


    };
```

Comment: Use Cloudinary 3rd party library for uploading image. Its a CDN where you can save the images and retrieve from it in different resolutions.

Comment: Seems you'r sending image as a file. You need to use _MultiPartEntity_ with volley.

Comment: `params.put("example_file",file.toString()`. Well if you have problems uploading a file than you should show exactly what and how you put content in `file`.

Comment: `You need to use MultiPartEntity with volley`. No. That is not true looking at that `x-www-form-urlencoded` sheme. If that indeed does work. But OP did not tell sadly.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void uploadImageWithStringParamsToServer() {
    SimpleMultiPartRequest smr = new SimpleMultiPartRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://139.59.16.103/addImage",
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d("Response", response);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }, 
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
    });

  smr.addStringParam("id", "821470");
  smr.addStringParam("type", "photos");
  smr.addFile("example_file", "2014-11-17 17.08.33-2.jpg");
  smr.setFixedStreamingMode(true);
  smr.setOnProgressListener(this);

  RequestQueue mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
  mRequestQueue.add(smr);
  mRequestQueue.start();
}
```

Comment: see https://github.com/DWorkS/VolleyPlus/blob/master/library/src/com/android/volley/request/SimpleMultiPartRequest.java @AnishKumar

Comment: Thanks @Clive Seebregts

Comment: @CliveSeebregts Suppose I get a uri (data.getData), from onActivityResult after selecting image from gallery. How do i pass this uri to   smr.addFile("example_file", "???")  in order to post the request?